# localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString not available in Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, nsstring

I'm trying to use `localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString()` method introduced in iOS 8:

```
let match = text.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchText)
```

Swift compiler says:

> 'String' does not have a member named 'localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString'

Documentation says:

> Swift automatically bridges between the String type and the NSString class.

So, what's going on here?

I know I can use `(title as NSString)`. I just want to know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need to cast it to not confuse the compiler I guess:

```
let match = (text as NSString).localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchText)
```

Comment: I want to know why it makes the compiler confused.

Comment: `text` is a `String`, so it is not treated as `NSString` unless you explicitly say so.

Comment: Two separate type cannot have same interface methods, but in this case one type can be cast to another.

Comment: What methods are you talking about? Metohds like `hasPrefix` are declared on both `String` and `NSString`, while `enumerateLinesUsingBlock`, for example, only works on `NSString`.

Comment: For example `componentsSeparatedByString`.

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByString` have separate definitions for both `String` and `NSString`. The return types even don't match.

Comment: Where is it defined for Swift?

Comment: I don't know where its defined. I am checking method declarations with alt+click in Xcode.

Comment: So, why isn't it bridged automatically? I would expect Swift to use its implementation without instructing the compiler.

Comment: Its auto bridged from method parameters and literals. In other cases you have to cast. See "Working with Cocoa Data Types” in "Using Swift with Objective-C" book.

Comment: It think the limitation is in there because one instance cannot be of two types at the same time.