# Check if a string exists in an array case insensitively

Tags: swift, contains

Declaration:

```
let listArray = ["kashif"]
let word = "kashif"
```

then this

```
contains(listArray, word)
```

Returns true but if declaration is:

```
let word = "Kashif"
```

then it returns false because comparison is case sensitive.

How to make this comparison case insensitive?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can use

```
word.lowercaseString
```

to convert the string to all lowercase characters

Answer (score 70):

**Xcode 8 • Swift 3 or later**

```
let list = ["kashif"]
let word = "Kashif"

if list.contains(where: {$0.caseInsensitiveCompare(word) == .orderedSame}) {
    print(true)  // true
}
```

alternatively:

```
if list.contains(where: {$0.compare(word, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame}) {
    print(true)  // true
}
```

if you would like to know the position(s) of the element in the array (it might find more than one element that matches the predicate):

```
let indices = list.indices.filter { list[$0].caseInsensitiveCompare(word) == .orderedSame }
print(indices)  // [0]
```

---

You can also use localizedStandardContains method which is case and diacritic insensitive and would match a substring as well:

```
func localizedStandardContains<T>(_ string: T) -> Bool where T : StringProtocol
```

> Discussion This is the most appropriate method for doing user-level string searches, similar to how searches are done generally in the system. The search is locale-aware, case and diacritic insensitive. The exact list of search options applied may change over time.

```
let list = ["kashif"]
let word = "Káshif"

if list.contains(where: {$0.localizedStandardContains(word) }) {
    print(true)  // true
}
```

Answer (score 19):

For checking if a string exists in a array (case insensitively), please use

```
listArray.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(word)
```

where listArray is the name of array 
and word is your searched text

This code works in Swift 2.2

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26175437/419348
`localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString` seems a method in `NSString`. But I don't like it's method signature. Maybe `containsIgnoringCase ` is better naming.

Comment: @AechoLiu I would prefer containsCaseInsensitive or caseInsensitiveContains. Btw you can implement your own https://stackoverflow.com/a/41232801/2303865

Comment: @Leo Thank your suggestion. I use Swift now. I like [its naming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30533007/419348).

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4**

Just make everything (queries and results) case insensitive.

```
for item in listArray {
    if item.lowercased().contains(word.lowercased()) {
        searchResults.append(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: contains() should be equals(), here.

Comment: Just depends how you want the search to work. For search queries, I prefer contains.

Comment: this is inefficient - it will cause `word` to be lower-cased on every iteration.

Answer (score 12):

You can add an extension:

Swift 5

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    func containsIgnoringCase(_ element: Element) -> Bool {
        contains { $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(element) == .orderedSame }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
["tEst"].containsIgnoringCase("TeSt") // true
```

Comment: Love this. Nice and clean :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
let loword = word.lowercaseString
let found = contains(listArray) { $0.lowercaseString == loword }
```

Answer (score 5):

For checking if a string exists in a array with more **Options**(caseInsensitive, anchored/search is limited to start)

#### using Foundation [`range(of:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416849-range)

```
let list = ["kashif"]
let word = "Kashif"


if list.contains(where: {$0.range(of: word, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil}) {
    print(true)  // true
}

if let index = list.index(where: {$0.range(of: word, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil}) {
    print("Found at index \(index)")  // true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

swift 5, swift 4.2 , use the code in the below.

```
let list = ["kAshif"]
let word = "Kashif"

if list.contains(where: { $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(word) == .orderedSame }) {
    print("contains is true")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 3.0:

Finding a case insensitive string in a string array is cool and all, but if you don't have an index it can not be cool for certain situations.

Here is my solution:

```
let stringArray = ["FOO", "bar"]()
if let index = stringArray.index(where: {$0.caseInsensitiveCompare("foo") == .orderedSame}) {
   print("STRING \(stringArray[index]) FOUND AT INDEX \(index)")
   //prints "STRING FOO FOUND AT INDEX 0"                                             
}
```

This is better than the other answers b/c you have index of the object in the array, so you can grab the object and do whatever you please :)

Comment: Note that it might occur more than once and this will give you only to the first index.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Govind Kumawat's answer

The simple comparison for a `searchString` in a `word` is:

```
word.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
```

As functions:

```
func containsCaseInsensitive(searchString: String, in string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}

func containsCaseInsensitive(searchString: String, in array: [String]) -> Bool {
    return array.contains {$0.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
}

func caseInsensitiveMatches(searchString: String, in array: [String]) -> [String] {
    return array.compactMap { string in
        return string.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            ? string
            : nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My example

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
    let countries = Countries.getAllCountries()
    filteredCountries = countries.filter() {
        return $0.name.containsString(searchText) || $0.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to search values from within model class, say

```
struct Country {
   var name: String
}
```

One case do case insensitive checks like below -

```
let filteredList = countries.filter({ $0.name.range(of: "searchText", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil })
```