# Searching a UITableView and ignoring punctuation

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

Is there a way to search through a UITableView and ignore certain characters like commas or dots?

I.e. I would like to search for "St George" but my data set contains "St. George" so the result is always zero.

**EDITED Q:**

```
 func filteredArray(searchText: NSString) {
    if searchText == "" {
        array_search = array_all
    } else {
        showTableViewResults()
        array_search.removeAll()
        for i in 0 ..< array_all.count {
            let object:MyObject = array_all[i]
            let languageSearchString = object.myObjectName
            let searchStr:String = languageSearchString!
            if searchStr.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased) {
                array_search.append(object)
            }
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    recordsFoundLabel.text = "records found: \(array_search.count)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter all characters thats not a letter out of your String before performing your search. The same applies to the table view data source elements. Also as mentioned by rmaddy you should implement a case insensitive search:

edit/update **Swift 5.2 or later**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func caseInsensitiveContains<S: StringProtocol>(_ string: S) -> Bool { range(of: string, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var letters: Self { filter(\.isLetter) }
}
```

---

Testing:

```
let search = "st george"
let tableViewSource = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "St. George"]

let filtered = tableViewSource.filter {
    $0.letters.caseInsensitiveContains(search.letters)
}
print(filtered)   // ["St. George"]
```

---

---

If you would like to literally just remove punctuation from your String (note that would keep the spaces in your String), you can do as follow:

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func removePunctuation() { removeAll(where: \.isPunctuation) }
}
```

---

```
extension Bool {
    var negated: Bool { !self }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var removingPunctuation: Self { filter(\.isPunctuation.negated) }
}
```

---

Testing:

```
let filtered = tableViewSource.filter {
    $0.removingPunctuation.caseInsensitiveContains(search.removingPunctuation)
}
print(filtered)   // ["St. George"]
```

---

If you would like to implement the same logic as Xcode autocomplete you would need to do a search for each character and change the startIndex of the string searched:

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func containsCharactersInSequence<S: StringProtocol>(_ string: S, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> (result: Bool, ranges: [Range<Index>]) {
        var found = 0
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        var index = string.startIndex
        var ranges: [Range<Index>] = []
        while index < string.endIndex,
            let range = self[startIndex...].range(of: string[index...index], options: options) {
            ranges.append(range)
            startIndex = range.upperBound
            string.formIndex(after: &index)
            found += 1
        }
        return (found == string.count, ranges)
    }
}
```

---

Playground Testing:

```
let search = "stgre"
let tableViewSource = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "St. George"]

let filtered = tableViewSource.filter {
    $0.containsCharactersInSequence(search, options: .caseInsensitive).result
}
print(filtered)   // ["St. George"]
```

Comment: This is a very strange and user unfriendly solution. It would find "St. George" if the user typed "Greg" but not if the user typed "george".

Comment: Not quite. Xcode autocomplete at least expects the search text characters to be found in the same order as a matching value. If I want Xcode to give me the `contains` method on a `String` object, I can type `otns`, for example, but not `ncs`, for example.

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for your answer. I am using an array of objects rather than an array of Strings so I got some trouble implementing your solutions. See edited Q for info. Thanks

Comment: Post you objects declaration, and the related code to your question,. Note: Not related to your issue, you should use String ONLY when coding in Swift3. No need to use NSString as the method type parameter

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply implement a function that for any given string, will return te same string without any point, (or whatever you want to erase); such as :

```
func erase(characters: [String], fromText text: String) -> String {
    var result = String()
    for character in text.characters {
         if !characters.contains(character) {
             result += String(character)
         }
    }
    return result
 }
```

(I cant test it from where i am but you get the idea right ?)

Hope it helps

Comment: It should also do a case-insensitive search (most likely).