# .Contains closure: 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context [Solution: Optional String issue]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, closures, contains

Using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31330465/7327018), I tried to do an insensitive-case search to find companies for a certain major, but I get the error "Expression 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context" at `let isFound =`.

**Why? How do I solve this?**

`company.majors` is a `String` array. `searchValue` is a lowercase `String`

```
let searchValue = filterOptItem.searchValue?.lowercased()
for company in allCompanies {
     //Insensitive case search
     let isFound = company.majors.contains({ $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(searchValue) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame })
     if (isFound) {
        filteredCompanies.insert(company)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SearchValue is an optional string.

If you are sure that searchValue can't be nil. Please use:

```
let isFound = company.majors.contains({ $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(searchValue!) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame })
```

If you are not sure, use:

```
if let searchValue = filterOptItem.searchValue?.lowercased(){
    for company in allCompanies {
         //Insensitive case search
         let isFound = company.majors.contains({ $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(searchValue) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame })
         if (isFound) {
            filteredCompanies.insert(company)
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends very much of a context and possible extensions, however cod itself seems wrong: you should either implicit closure `let isFound = company.majors.contains{ $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(searchValue) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame }` or use parameter name `where:`.

Fixed code work fine for Swift4 playgrounds:

```
let company = (name: "Name", majors: ["a", "b", "cas"])
let searchValue = "a"
let isFound = company.majors.contains{ $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(searchValue) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 , Swift 4

```
//MARK:- You will find the array when its filter in "filteredStrings" variable you can check it by count if count > 0 its means you have find the results

let itemsArray = ["Google", "Goodbye", "Go", "Hello"]
let searchToSearch = "go"

    let filteredStrings = itemsArray.filter({(item: String) -> Bool in

        let stringMatch = item.lowercased().range(of: searchToSearch.lowercased())
        return stringMatch != nil ? true : false
    })
    print(filteredStrings)


    if (filteredStrings as NSArray).count > 0
    {
        //Record found
    }
    else
    {
        //Record Not found
    }
```