# find duplicate names on list and report to user

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a validator to check the duplicate name on the company array. It has one problem in that it failed checking names like BWM and Sony. Can someone help me to fix my duplicate array?

```
let isDuplicate = accounts?.contains {
   $0.displayName!.lowercased() == txtfCompanyName!.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: [" "]).lowercased()
}
```

Comment: And why did it fail checking those company names? You need to supply more info like some sample data from the array and an example that fails

Comment: This looks like it should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61669285/6257435